# Rank 1 kakita applied to damage

Tags: l5r, l5r-4e

Following what it is said on the book of fourth edition, rank 1 kakita bushi "The way of the crane":

> You gain a bonus of +1k1 plus your School Rank to the total of all attack and Focus rolls while assuming the Center Stance.

Does this mean that it gets a +1k1 to only hit, or to hit and damage rolls?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky thing Let's go step by step!

## What does Way of the Crane do?

+1k1 Attack Rolls and Focus Rolls, as well as in rounds after exiting Center Stance.

### When do Attack Rolls happen?

The rules are in the L5R Core Rules on page 82 (emphasis mine):

> #### Attack & Defense
>
> Any attack a character makes against an opponent requires a
>   roll, typically a Skill Roll that includes a Weapon Skill as one
>   of its components. Attacks may be melee or ranged in nature,
>   depending upon the weapon being used. These rolls are made
>   using the rules included for Skill Rolls above, and the result
>   of an **attack roll** is compared to the opponent’s Armor TN. [...] If the result
>   of the **attack roll** meets or exceeds the target’s Armor TN, then
>   the attack was successful and the opponent was struck with
>   the weapon in question. **Damage** must now be rolled.
>
> Penalties or bonuses may be applied to **attack rolls** for a
>   variety of reasons. [...]
>
> #### Wounds
>
> [...] The Wounds inflicted by an **attack** fill up
>   these Wound Ranks in order[...]

### When do Focus Rolls happen?

Focus rolls only happen during Iaijutsu duels as step 2 after the assessment roll.

### What does happen after center Stance?

With Way of the Crane, you get +10 Initiative for that round and +1k1+Void Ring on *any one* roll (standard) and +1k1 on *all* **attack rolls** (Way of the Crane).

## Conclusion:

*Attacks* are an action that first demands a successful *attack roll* which then demands to roll for *damage*, a distinct and separate roll, that does not apply the same modifiers. You **don't** apply Way of the Crane on rolls for damage, but you could apply the standard bonus from Center Stance to a damage roll - provided you hit.